# Pass query string parameter to UrlHelper.Action method in .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have method like

```
 UrlHelper.Action("login", "Authentication", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme);
```

I want to pass query string parameter like "referrer?" = pageName to this method. How can I do it?

Comment: `UrlHelper.Action("login", "Authentication", new { referrer = "..." })`

Comment: Thanks... @Stephen Muecke.. I am trying to get the value of referrer in controller by using `code` string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["referrer"].ToString(); but it gives me null.. Any help?

Comment: Yuu said you want a query string so you method needs to be `public ActionResult Login(string referrer)` (and the parameter will be bound with the value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to decalre your parameter like this:

```
UrlHelper.Action("login", "Authentication", new { referrer = "Page Name" })
```

Then get the parameter in your Action:

```
Request.Params["referrer"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Example

```
Url.Action("GetValues", "Home", new { Area = "Solan", id =Model.Id})
```

Here Area and id are the parameters passed to the GetValues method inside Home controller

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Is it enough @TobySpeight